# How to autoshrink text in textFiled depending on UIScreen width

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have such a problem, I can't solve.

I have a textField, with following constrains

Font size is 27
[image: following constrains]

I have set `Automatically Adjust Font` in IB and set minimal font size to 25 with `Adjust to fit option`

But, when I'm launching on iPhone 5 screen, my text Field font size only changes when it reaches the width screen. On contrast I want my textField to set the proper minimal size, when my screen is loading, not to shrink text, while I'm typing.

Can I somehow do it in IB?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

We have option to add different fonts for different size devices.
[Screenshot of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBXeJ.png)